# Will the diode work at -273°c or 0 K ? how will very low temperature affect its operation?

Tags: diodes

I am just learning about semiconductors and this question arose. I can't find proper answers on Google.

Comment: Nothing works at 0K as nothing can reach 0K

Comment: hard to say, thermal contraction could easily break the package, hence the performance.

Comment: Go read this article, the relevant part is at the bottom: http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/extrinsi.htm  So below 70 K most PN junctions will stop working. Most practical devices stop working at much higher temperatures. Most manufacturers only guarantee operation down to -40 Celcius because testing at lower temperatures is costly.

Comment: Semiconductors seem to go low conductance (high resistance) at low temperatures, like below 10 degrees K. Don't know about *junctions* of different doping at these temperatures.

Answer (score 3):

Normal diodes work fine down to below 77K (liquid nitrogen). Below that, such as at 4K (liquid Helium) and below they often do strange things- carriers freeze out, they turn into oscillators, show [hysteresis](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5436306/?reload=true) and so on.

Some specially made silicon diodes will work as low as 1.4K (we use them as sensors).